# On the upper bound of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^m_{i}$ subject to the conditions $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^2_{i}=n$

Tags: inequality

> Let $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}$ are real numbers, and such 
>   $$\begin{cases}
> x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}=0\\
> x^2_{1}+x^2_{2}+\cdots+x^2_{n}=n
> \end{cases}$$
>   Let $\alpha_{m}=\displaystyle\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^m_{i}$

This problem is from Mitrinovic D.S Analytic inequalities (Springer 1970) Page 347.

M.LAKSHMANAMURTI He proved that
$$\alpha_{m}\le\dfrac{(n-1)^{m-1}+(-1)^m}{n(n-1)^{(m/2)-1}}$$

I have find the proof somedays, at last I  can't find the 1950's paper,can you someone find the full paper? or post this question  answer here? Thanks

[image]

Comment: IIRC, that needs real $m\ge3$ and of course $n\ge2$ integer.

Comment: @Macavity ,Thanks,can you have solve it?

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310625/on-the-upper-bound-of-sum-i-1nxm-i-subject-to-the-condtions-sum-i

Answer (score 1):

The idea is roughly that we want $x_n$ to be as big as possible because $a^m+b^m \leq (a+b)^m$ for all $m\geq1$ and $a,b \geq 0$.

Which means the upper bound is when $x_n$ is as big as possible and the other $x_i \approx 0$.

From the second condition we know that $x_n^2 \leq n$ so $x_n \approx \sqrt{n}$

From the first condition we need that $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i \approx -\sqrt{n}$ and they are as small as possible so taking $x_i = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n-1$ and $x_n = \sqrt{n-1}$

These numbers fulfill the first and second condition, and we just need to evaluate

$\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} x_i^m = \frac{1}{n} \sqrt{(n-1)^m}+(-1)^m \frac{n-1}{n} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}})^m = \frac{1}{n}(n-1)^{\frac{m}{2}}+\frac{(-1)^m}{n (n-1)^{m/2-1}} = \frac{(n-1)^{m-1}+(-1)^m}{n(n-1)^{m/2-1}}$.

What is left is to prove that $x_n \not > \sqrt{n-1}$ even by a little amount(i will try to solve it).

Comment: You're exactly right with your choices of the $x_i$  such that $\alpha_m$ becomes as big as possible.

Comment: I continued your work, Ahmad.

Comment: @Andreas you did all the work.

Answer (score 1):

Following Ahmads answer, we need to show that $x_i = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n-1$ and $x_n = \sqrt{n-1}$ indeed produces the maximum value of $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^m$, which is $\alpha_m^* = \dfrac{(n-1)^{m-1}+(-1)^m}{(n-1)^{(m/2)-1}}$. Actually, [this paper](http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_pdf.php?issn=0013-6018&vol=57&iss=2&rank=3) (*Some constrained optimization problems in elementary statistics*, by Wolfgang Stadje (2002)) cites that M. LAKSHMANAMURTI in the mentioned 1950 article is using exactly  these values to prove the claim.

Let us change the variables to $x_i = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}} + y_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n-1$ and $x_n = \sqrt{n-1} + y_n$. Then we have to observe  $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = 0$. Further, demanding $n = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ gives, when using $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = 0$, the condition $y_n = - \frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{2 n } \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2$. So it is only possible to use negative $y_n$.

Expanding $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^m$ to first order in $y_i$, we obtain (again using $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = 0$)

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^m  = \alpha_m^* + m (n-1)^{-\frac{m-1}{2}} [(n-1)^{m-1} - (-1)^{m-1}] y_n
$$

Since $(n-1)^{m-1} - (-1)^{m-1} \ge 0$, and since $y_n <0$, we have that the value of  $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^m$ will actually not increase in the vicinity of the original values for $x_i$, no matter what the changes $y_i$ are. This shows that  the original values for $x_i$ indeed locally produce the highest value of $\alpha_m$.

Comment: So your derivation shows it is a local rather than the global maximum, right?

Comment: @Hans Yes, local maximum is proved. That doesn't mean "rather than" the global maximum, since every global maximum is as well a local maximum. So, a necessary condition has been proved, and further arguments are needed which makes it sufficient.

Comment: Yes, the word "rather" was not the best choice. I meant the proof was insufficient to show it was the global maximum. By the way, the paper you cited is an interesting one.